# When running COPY command on Redshift, how do I specify there is no quote character?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I've been using weird quote characters to have less chance of import issues

```
 CSV QUOTE AS '\`'
```

But really my dataset is tab delimited. There is no quoting with any characters at all. How do I tell redshift I don't use quote character?

Comment: Just say `CSV` without the `QUOTE` part?

Comment: I see this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-format.html#copy-csv
    
    QUOTE [AS] 'quote_character' Optional. Specifies the character to be used as the quote character when using the CSV parameter. The default is a double quotation mark ( " ).

Does that mean that if I leave out QUOTE AS, it defaults to double quote?

Comment: Can confirm, by default if no QUOTE part is specified, it will use double quotes.

Comment: Yes, but it will not *require* a quote. If you are using tab-delimited, make sure you include `DELIMITER AS '\t'`

Comment: It appears to force a quote DELIMITER ',' CSV QUOTE AS '"'  == DELIMITER ','; . If I don't specify quote it defaults to double quote. Wish there was feature like CSV QUOTE AS FALSE

Comment: I am now confused! Could you please supply some sample lines of your file and the incorrect result you're seeing in Redshift?
 Are your files Tab or Comma delimited?

Comment: Look again at John answer. When you do DELIMITER '\t', you don't specify CSV at all, btw.